# border:none not working on an image set using background

Tags: html, css

K so I have an image in my html and I am settings its src using css and `background: url()` the reason for this is because I want to toggle the class on click so that I go back and forth between images. Everything works except for the fact that my image has a border and nothing I do seems to get rid of the stupid thing.

Here is the html:

```
<img class="minus" />
```

and here is the css:

```
.minus{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 -3px 5px;
  float:right;
  background: url(/images/mobile/minus.png) no-repeat;
  border: none;
  display:block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

I have tried everything I can think of `border:0px; border:0; border-width: 0px; border-style:none;` anything I could find on here or on the web basicly and nothing will get rid of the stupid border. Any insight would be appreciated.

Edit: using google chrome.

Comment: does minus.png have a border in the image?

Comment: put a fiddle up to demonstrate the issue please.  or a page.  mention the browser you are using as well.

Comment: developing on a local server instance so I don't have a page to point to.

Comment: You shouldn't be applying a background image to an image tag. Perhaps you should use a div or span instead. Plus, not including a source on an image tag is not valid code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm certainly able to reproduce this error in Chrome. Here's a demo:

```css
.minus{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 -3px 5px;
  background: url('http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png');
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img class="minus">
```

However, [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html) specifies (emphasis mine):

> The SRC attribute specifies the URI for the image to be embedded. Its syntax is the same as that of the HREF attribute of the  tag. **SRC is mandatory.**

Setting a CSS `background-image` is not the same as setting the `src` HTML attribute of `<img>`... and perhaps that's your problem. You should consider using a different element, e.g.: a `<span>`:

```css
.minus {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 -3px 5px;
  background: url('http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png');  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
}
```

```html
<span class="minus"></span>
```

Comment: accepting this as the answer, though a div (or anything block level was not acceptable in this instance) I got it to work with out a border by using an <a> tag. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burhans/sPZ8R/) that uses a div with the class (I see no border).  When I try an img with the class, it shows nothing (in firefox 7)